# How can I get the position of the list item clicked while using Firebase RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using Firebase RecyclerAdapter rather than using the normal RecyclerAdapter. I wanted to store the position of the list Item which is clicked.
The code for the HomeFragment is below

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProductAdapter adapter;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        String u = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(u).child("Products"), Product.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ProductAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }
}
```

The code for the ProductAdapter class is given below

```
package com.example.prj;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ProductAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ProductAdapter";
    ImageView btn_stock;
    public ProductAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Product model) {
        holder.pname.setText(model.getPname());
        holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image);
           }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }



    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView pname, price, description;
        ImageView image ;
        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_name);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_price);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_description);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_image);




        }
    }
```

Using the position of the list item which is clicked I want to make the list item expandable.Like the users clicks on the list item and the list item expands and shows some more details about that item..If someone has the solution for that please help me in that also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In `onBindViewHolder()` set the item click listener:**

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Product model) {

.....
.....
....

//here set the click of the item

holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

//here do something with position that is passed in the onBindViewHolder
//if you clicked item 1 the position is 0
//if you clicked item 2 the position is 1
..............

Log.d("POSITION" , String.valueOf(position));


}


});
```

**In your Viewholder add the `view` parameter**

```
class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView pname, price, description;
ImageView image ;

//here
View view;

public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    //set it here
    view = itemView;
    ......
    ......
```